# Merge [Crashplan] and [crashplan-central]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

## TROGDOR!!!!

[image]

Both [crashplan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crashplan) and [crashplan-central](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crashplan-central) refer to the same product.  [crashplan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crashplan) should be the root.

Comment: Doesn't one require an internet connection (local network backups), while the other doesn't?

Comment: Crashplan central is the online interface to crashplan.  To me they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Crashplan Central is the feature that allows you to use their servers as a backup destination:

> CrashPlan Central is the cloud backup destination for CrashPlan+, providing online storage for your personal files in our secure data centers located around the world.

It costs money (as part of Crashplan+ or up). Crashplan itself is free for backups to other systems on your local network (or your own servers somewhere).

It's a significantly distinct subset of the program's functionality and the tag is useful if you're specifically asking about the central online storage. Something comparable would probably be [outlook-web-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access).